# SQL Joining Two Statements

Tags: php, sql, join

I haven't found any SQL joining problems quite this big, this is the problem: I have two SQL statements, one gets the money funded out into separate groups, and one gets the money that's been spent in those groups, how would I join them together so that it shows the "Budget" and "Expenses" together? 
Pretty much, instead of having Department, Funding Category, Budget and Department, Funding Category, Expenses tables, I would like one Department, Funding Category, Budget, Expenses table.

```
SELECT st.name as "Department", sft.longname as "Funding Category", sum(sf.amount) as "Budget" 
FROM 
money_type as st, 
money_funding_type as sft, 
money_funding as sf 
WHERE 
st.ID = sf.type_ID AND 
sft.ID = sf.funding_ID 
GROUP BY 
sf.type_id, sf.funding_id 

SELECT st.name as "Department", sft.longname as "Funding Category", sum(si.amount) as "Expenses" 
FROM 
money_type as st, 
money_funding_type as sft, 
money_invoice as si 
WHERE 
st.ID = si.type_ID AND 
sft.ID = si.funding_ID 
GROUP BY 
si.type_id, si.funding_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following.  The first query "AllTypes" is to get distinct id/types of the possible data available and not a Cartesian.  From that, simple joins to the type and funding type to get the descriptions.

Then, two more selects simplified on their own elements of money_funding / money_invoice just getting their "id" fields and sum of amounts, so for each budget and expense, you will have 1 record per type/funding.  These are then left-joined to the "AllTypes", and if they have a corresponding value, grabbed for the result, else 0.

Extra line breaks between the joins for readability only

```
SELECT
      st.name as "Department", 
      sft.longname as "Funding Category", 
      coalesce( Budgets.Budget, 0 ) as Budget,
      coalesce( Expenses.Expense, 0 ) as Expense,
      coalesce( Budgets.Budget, 0 ) - coalesce( Expenses.Expense, 0 ) as AmtRemain
   from 
      ( select distinct
              type_id,
              funding_id
           from
              money_funding
        union
        SELECT distinct
              type_id,
              funding_id
           from
              money_invoice  ) AllTypes

         JOIN money_type as st
            ON AllTypes.type_id = st.id

         JOIN money_funding_type as sft
            ON AllTypes.funding_id = sft.id

         LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 
                           sf.type_id,
                           sf.funding_id,
                           sum(sf.amount) as "Budget" 
                        FROM 
                           money_funding as sf 
                        GROUP BY 
                           sf.type_id, 
                           sf.funding_id ) Budgets
            ON AllTypes.type_id = Budgets.Type_id
            AND AllTypes.funding_id = Budgets.Funding_ID

         LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 
                           si.type_id, 
                           si.funding_id,
                           sum(si.amount) as "Expense" 
                        FROM 
                           money_invoice as si 
                        GROUP BY 
                           si.type_id, 
                           si.funding_id ) Expenses
            ON AllTypes.type_id = Expenses.Type_id
            AND AllTypes.funding_id = Expenses.Funding_ID
```

The "AllTypes" query, you might need to remove the second "DISTINCT" clause as the first probably applies to the entire "AllTypes" query and might give you an error.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
SELECT  st.name as "Department", 
        COALESCE(sft.longname,sfti.longname) as "Funding Category", 
        sum(sf.amount) as "Budget",
        sum(si.amount) as "Expenses" 
FROM    money_type as st LEFT JOIN

        money_funding as sf  ON st.ID = sf.type_ID LEFT JOIN
        money_funding_type as sft ON sft.ID = sf.funding_ID LEFT JOIN

        money_invoice as si ON st.ID = si.type_ID LEFT JOIN
        money_funding_type as sfti  ON sfti.ID = si.funding_ID
GROUP BY    st.name, 
            COALESCE(sft.longname,sfti.longname)
```

Comment: It finally finished, doesn't work. Where the value for expenses should be 475.9, it is 951.8, where the value should return 26452.19, it returns 72388013.48009163

Comment: show us your actual table structures, and some sample data and we can he a look. This was a best effeort based on the queries you provided.

Comment: [funding table](http://imgur.com/VrMxPLQ)  
[funding_type table](http://imgur.com/ibnEwOO)  
[invoice table](http://imgur.com/TkOWql3)  
[money_type table](http://imgur.com/pdNObos)

Answer (score 0):

use FULL OUTER JOIN to join both Invoice and Funding, and then group by moneytype, funding and invoice.

Comment: Could you give me the SQL for it? I do PHP not SQL, I don't really know how this works.